# Two tags for Middle Ages

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, tag-synonyms

At the moment, we have tag [medieval](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval) and tag [middle-ages](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-ages). Should they be merged?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for bringing this up, and sorry for initially missing your post. I have now merged these tags.